# Center text beside image

Tags: css, center

Can somebody help me to center the text (link) to the image? Please have a look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBssG/).

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 1):

Use `vertical-align` property

```
a {
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/UBssG/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Add vertical-align:middle to your links:

```
a {
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBssG/3/)**.

Answer (score 1):

write `vertical-align:middle;` in your `a` tag

```
a {
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/UBssG/4/